# Sql server export table to excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv

I’m trying to export a table into excel/csv , but I’m having trouble because of one column, which is long and has been concatenated with delimiter of “char(10) + char(13)” for a new lines . When I copy all the data from sql server management studio and use “save as” csv file, the output gets broken . Every place that there is a use of a new line , the output get stretched to more than 1 row and breaks the columns position.

I also tried using the export wizard ( don’t know if it will make a difference ) but with no success as the export keeps failing on the last step (getting a warning of “potential lost conversion from nvarchar to longtext) with error of  “data conversion failed ..”

Comment: Excel isn't `csv`. The `xlsx` format is a zip package of xml files. What did you try, where is the code? `Save as CSV` from SSMS is *not* an export option, it's just a convenience tool.

Comment: SSMS has an import/export wizard that can generate reusable SSIS packages. You can access it from `Tasks > Import Data` or `Tasks > Export Data`. You can export to a *lot* of formats, including real Excel files. You can open the generated package in SQL Server Data Tools to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow multiline fields in csv, those fields have to be enclosed in quotes:

```
123,"multiline
field",456
789,second record,147
```

If this is not the case in your generated csv you might have to tell the generator to quote the fields.

If the quotes are already there the csv is valid and any decent reader should take care of those multiline fields. Of course, if you open the file in Notepad you'll still see multiple lines per record, which is normal.

Comment: I’ve used a different approach (fixed the export issue) but this worked as well. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such issues, you need to clean the data by replacing the carriage return (char(13)) and line feed (char(10)) in your SELECT statement using the following query:

SELECT replace(replace([ColumnName], char(10), ''), char(13), '') 
FROM [dbo].[yourTableName]

Comment: They’re not there by accident , I need them to appear in the excel line by line

Comment: @Yossi you didn't explain what you tried. Save As from SSMS isn't an export tool, it's a convenience command. There's an actual Import/Export Data wizard in SSMS which generates reusable SSIS packages

Comment: Hey Yossi, Could you please give some query structure or table structure And some example which shows the requirement for more clarification.